# Dell XPS 13 7390 laptop with Ubuntu 18.04.4. camera suddenly stopped working

Tags: 18.04, dell, webcam

I bought XPS laptop 2-3 months ago and it came with Ubuntu. It didn't work properly, so I installed Ubuntu version 18.04. Everything worked great until this morning meet call:

- Before joining the call, I opened the camera and I could see myself clearly.
- Once I joined the call, I noticed that the camera is off in the meet. However, the camera light was on.
- On Google chrome, camera was not found.
- After the meeting, I restarted the laptop, and since then, I get "no device found" on Cheese, or "no camera found" on Skype, Meet, Zoom, etc.

I searched a lot and couldn't found the solution to this problem, all the question finished with the fix of "press the Fn+F6 key" or similar, to turn the camera on. But this laptop doesn't have such key :(.

I hope somebody can help me, I'm really desperate and need this.
If the hardware is broken, I still have a warranty so I would return the laptop. But I would like to make sure it's not a software issue, since in Spain Dell is not giving the support for Ubuntu and they blame all on it.

This is the laptop: https://www.dell.com/support/article/es-es/sln318246/dell-xps-13-7390-usage-and-troubleshooting-guide?lang=en&ref=topsolutions

On terminal, `lsusb` is showing this:

```
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 009: ID 8087:0029 Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 05e3:0751 Genesys Logic, Inc. 
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 046d:c52b Logitech, Inc. Unifying Receiver
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 1a40:0801 Terminus Technology Inc. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

And `lsusb -V` gives me this:

```
lsusb (usbutils) 007
```